# How to autoscale a SKLearn job on sagemaker

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I want to launch a SKLearn job using `sagemaker`. The way I do this is as follows:

```
from sagemaker.sklearn.estimator import SKLearn

FRAMEWORK_VERSION = '0.23-1' 
script_path = 'main.py'

sklearn = SKLearn(
    entry_point=os.path.join(script_path),
    framework_version=FRAMEWORK_VERSION,
    instance_type='ml.m5.2xlarge',
    source_dir='src',
    output_path='my/output/path',
)
```

I am not sure if the instance_type that I have chosen is enough (in terms of memory etc) for my application though.

Is there a way to "let sagemaker" decide on the instance type ?

Or, is there a way to choose an instance_type and if along the way it is about to run out of memory, the sagemaker to automatically scale up ?

Comment: Not as far as I know. There is, however, an API for recommending the best inference type: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/create-inference-recommendations-job.html . You can also run the scikit learn image in docker on your local machine to see how it performs, and guess the right instance size compared to your machien

Answer (score 0):

Automatic scale-up feature for Training doesn't exist in SageMaker at  this time.

On a separate note, for selecting the right instance type for inference, we have an instance recommender service (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/inference-recommender.html).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31137280)

Comment: On the face of it, this *does* look like an answer to the question "*How to autoscale a SKLearn job on sagemaker*" - but with an additional line which could be useful.

Comment: @AliaksandrS. just checking if the changes I made provide enough clarity.